# Dishwasher not draining before and after pump replacement

Tags: repair, kitchens, dishwasher

I have an 8 year old he dishwasher(GSD4060D35SS). It developed a problem where it wouldn’t drain at the end of the cycle. I replaced the pump and solenoid after discovering some physical damage to the impeller of the pump. The dishwasher drained without issue once. The next time there seemed to be water left over after the rinse cycle(clean water with no suds almost to heating element) and the next time it had standing water with soap in it leading me to think it didn’t completely drain from either the wash or rinse cycle. Is there anything else I should check? When it drains there is a steady stream of water into the disposal unit and no indication of a blockage in the hose.  When water is in the bottom of the dishwasher if I run a reset cycle the water will gradually drain.  Sometimes with one reset cycle and sometimes it takes several to evacuate the water.

Comment: Does the drain hose have a proper high loop? It should climb up above the drain and then go back down. Not having a high loop will cause issues with back flow (i.e. the dishwasher drains, but at the end of the cycle there is left over water)

Answer (score 2):

There is a float/sensor in dishwashers that tells it when there is water in the unit.

You might have an object that is jamming it up or it's sticking.   It should be an easy fix (if that's it).